# How to copy the message payload of direct channel to recovery channel in gateway?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a 'datachannel' which gets the result set from DB using inbound-channel adapter.
Here i am getting a field called 'process_id' from DB.After calling an external system through int:**http-outbound gateway** i am defining a recovery-channel. I want to do an update query only for that process_id.But i am unable to get the process id in the recovery channel.Getting an exception invalid property "payload[process_id]"..Is there anyway to pass the process_id to the recovery channel,so that i can perform my update query in a  like this

> int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter query="update TBL_RECEIPT set receipt_status=1 
>   where process_id in (:payload[process_id])" data-source="dataSource" channel="errors"/>

For clarity,below is spring-integration xml configuration

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
 xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream-4.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd">

 <int:channel id="requestchannel"></int:channel>
 <int:channel id="xtifyrequestchannel"></int:channel>
 <int:channel id="xtifyresponsechannel"></int:channel>
 <int:channel id="tpgrequestchannel"></int:channel>
 <int:channel id="tpgresponsechannel"></int:channel>
   <int:channel id="xtifyerrorchannel">
 </int:channel>

 <int:channel id="tpgerrorchannel">
 </int:channel>

 <int:channel id="executerchannel">
  <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" />
 </int:channel>

 <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2" />

 <bean id="pollerdatamapper" class="main.java.com.as.poller.PollerDataMapper" />

 <bean id="pollerservice" class="main.java.com.as.poller.PollerService" />

 <bean id="requestFactory"
  class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
  <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
  <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
 </bean>

 <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger"
  level="INFO" />

 <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="datachannel"
  query="select loyalty_id,process_id,mobile_uid,mobile_os from TBL_RECEIPT where r_cre_time=(select min(r_cre_time) from TBL_RECEIPT where receipt_status=0)"
  data-source="dataSource" max-rows-per-poll="1" row-mapper="pollerdatamapper">

  <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
  </int:poller>

 </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>


 <int:gateway id="requestGateway" service-interface="main.java.com.as.poller.RequestGateway"
  default-request-channel="requestchannel" default-reply-timeout="20000">
  <int:method name="pushNotification" />
  <int:method name="sendTPGRequest" request-channel="tpgrequestchannel">
   <int:header name="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data" />
  </int:method>
 </int:gateway>

 <int:object-to-json-transformer
  input-channel="requestchannel" output-channel="xtifyrequestchannel"></int:object-to-json-transformer>

 <int-http:outbound-gateway id="xtifygateway"
  request-channel="xtifyrequestchannel" reply-channel="xtifyresponsechannel" request-factory="requestFactory"
  url="${xtifyUrl}" http-method="POST">
  <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
   <int:retry-advice max-attempts="3" recovery-channel="xtifyerrorchannel">
   </int:retry-advice>
  </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
 </int-http:outbound-gateway>

 <int-http:outbound-gateway id="tpggateway"
  request-channel="tpgrequestchannel" reply-channel="tpgresponsechannel"
  request-factory="requestFactory" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
  url="${tpg_url}" http-method="POST">
  <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
   <int:retry-advice max-attempts="3" recovery-channel="tpgerrorchannel">
   </int:retry-advice>
  </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
 </int-http:outbound-gateway>

 <int:json-to-object-transformer
  input-channel="tpgresponsechannel" type="main.java.com.as.rest.response.TPGResponse" />


 <int:service-activator input-channel="datachannel"
  output-channel="executerchannel" ref="pollerservice" method="getRecordFromPoller">
 </int:service-activator>

 <int:service-activator input-channel="executerchannel"
  ref="pollerservice" method="getDataFromExecuterChannel">
 </int:service-activator>

 <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
  id="tpgsystemfailure"
  query="update TBL_RECEIPT set receipt_status=1 
  where process_id in (:payload.failedMessage.payload[process_id])"
  data-source="dataSource" channel="tpgerrorchannel" />

 <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
  id="xtifysystemfailure"
  query="update TBL_RECEIPT set receipt_status=4 where process_id in (:payload.failedMessage.payload[process_id])"
  data-source="dataSource" channel="xtifyerrorchannel" />
  
  <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
  id="xtifysystemsuccess"
  query="update TBL_RECEIPT set receipt_status=5 where process_id in (:payload.process_id)"
  data-source="dataSource" channel="xtifyresponsechannel" />
  
  
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recovery-channel` gets an `ErrorMessage`. The payload is a `MessagingException` with two properties `failedMessage` and `cause`.

Use `payload.failedMessage.payload[process_id]`.

Comment: You are the man!This is working as a charm.One doubt: this was my flow..datachannel->tpgrequestchannel->tpgresponsechannel->errors...Can you please tell me how i am able to access the process_id even in my "errors" ?

Comment: I am not sure what your new question is given that you said what I just told you worked.

Comment: it is working..i asked it just to know..how i got process_id in my recovery-channel also.Just for an understanding...

Comment: Look at the `ErrorMessage`; it's payload is a `MessagingException` with cause and `failedMessage` - which is your original message. Hence `payload.failedMessage.payload[process_id]`. You could also add a transformer `expression="payload.failedMessage"` to discard the exception and then you can use your original code `payload[process_id]`.

Comment: Great..:) I dont see 3 retries happening in my <int:http outbound gateway> where i am retrying only the web service call.Can you please look if my configuration is wrong ?Should i ask it as a separate question ?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` to see the retry activity. If you still see problems, ask a new question.

Comment: I have turned it on..posted the error log at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bfae50a3eb66c3a69cb1 ,since it will be too big here.can you please have a look ?

Comment: I need to see the prior log entries.

Comment: Hi Sir,log entries available at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac3cd21a6de11097cf62

Comment: Your configuration above no longer matches what's in the log. For example, `tpgerrorchannel` does not exist above. Please edit your question with your current config. The log implies that `max-attempts` is 0. However, I don't see how it's possible to get `Sending ErrorMessage :failedMessage` without seeing `Retry failed last attempt:` immediately before it, regardless of the retry settings. By the way, it's generally easier to debug Spring Integration apps if you include the class name `%c{1}` (log4j) and thread `%t` in the log entries.

Comment: Perhaps your logging DEBUG config doesn't include `org.springframework.retry` ?

Comment: org.springframework.retry=DEBUG worked. Now i can see this in log DEBUG - Checking for rethrow: count=3
DEBUG - Retry failed last attempt: count=3.  :) So org.springframework.retry should be separately given ?is it not part of springframework.integration ?

Comment: Correct. It's a separate shared project  used by multiple top level projects, Spring Batch, Spring AMQP, etc as well as Spring Integration. 7 comments ago, I suggested turning on DEBUG for all of `org.springframework` to see spring-retry log entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98050/discussion-between-chungunuvavaa-and-gary-russell).